# Python Networkx: edges not taking proper color, while specifying node positions

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am pretty novice in Python and started learning networkx to plot a graph, or road network.
I have to specify, the node positions. The edge color should be dependent on the values of the edges. I tried using pandas dataframe to generate edges. The edge colors work fine when position is not specified.
An example is attached.

**When not specifying positions**

```
# Build a dataframe with your connections
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'from':['A', 'B', 'C','A'], 'to':['D', 'A', 'E','C'], 'value':[1, 10, 5, 5]})
df

# Build your graph
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from', 'to', create_using=nx.Graph() )

# Custom the nodes:
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_color='skyblue', node_size=1500, edge_color=df['value'], width=10.0, edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
```

Here the edge colors are perfect

[image]

**When specifying positions**

```
pos = {'A': (0,1), 'D': (1,2) , 'B': (2,3) , 'C': (6,5), 'E': (0,0)}

nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_color='skyblue', node_size=1500, edge_color=df['value'], width=10.0, edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
```

Here node positions are perfect, but edge colors according to value are wrong:

[image]

I also tried putting position like the following -

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ "Nodes": ['A','D','B','C','E'], "x": [0,1,2,6,0], "y": [1,2,3,5,0]})
for i in df2.index:
    G.add_node(df2.loc[i, "Nodes"], df2=(nodes.loc[i, "x"], df2.loc[i, "y"]))
```

But, the problem in output remains they same.

Comment: What makes you think the output is wrong? In both images, all edges are light blue, except for the edge between A and B, which is dark blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed as you mention the edge color *is* determined by the values of the edges, as the `edge_color` numeric values are mapped to colors through the specified `edge_cmap`. What is causing confusion here is the specific arrangement of the coordinates, since the edge connecting `(A,D)` is overlapped by the one connecting `(A,B)`:

```
pos = {'A': (0,1), 'D': (1,2) , 'B': (2,3) , 'C': (6,5), 'E': (0,0)}
```

[image]

If we slightly change the coordinates of `D`, you'll see that the edge has the expected color:

```
pos = {'A': (0,1), 'D': (4,1) , 'B': (2,3) , 'C': (6,5), 'E': (0,0)}

nx.draw(G, pos, 
        with_labels=True, 
        node_color='skyblue', 
        node_size=1500, 
        edge_color=df['value'], 
        width=10.0, 
        edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
```

[image]

Comment: okk. Thanks. I screwed while creating the example. The main file is still giving problems, can I share the excels and code with you?

Comment: Here is the link to the detailed problem and complete code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62106487/python-networkx-with-pandas-edgelist-edges-not-taking-proper-color-while-speci