# Python Networkx with_pandas_edgelist: edges not taking proper color, while specifying node positions

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am pretty new to Python and started learning networkx to plot a graph for a road network. I have to specify, the node positions. The edge color should be dependent on the weights of the edges. I tried using pandas dataframe to generate edges. The edge colors work fine when position is not specified. The code is attached.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Necessary file-paths
l1 = 'file1.xlsx'
l2 = "file2.xlsx"

n1 = pd.read_excel(l1)
n1.head(10)
```

[image: It looks something like this]

```
n2 = pd.read_excel(l2)
n2.head(2)
```

[image: It looks like this]

```
# Building graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(n1, 'Start Node', 'End Node', create_using=nx.Graph())

# Defining positions
pos = {}
for n in G.nodes():
    i = n2[n2["Nodes"] == n].index[0]
    pos[n] = (n2.loc[i, "x"], n2.loc[i, "y"])

# Plot the Graph
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_color='pink', node_size=30, alpha=0.8, font_size=2,
        edge_color=n1['Capacity'], width=1.0, figsize = (18,18), style="solid", edge_cmap=plt.cm.jet)

# Save the Figure
plt.savefig('Network.png', dpi=1000, facecolor='w', edgecolor='w',orientation='portrait',  
            papertype=None, format=None,transparent=False, bbox_inches=None, pad_inches=0.1)
```

[image: It creates a graph like this]

However, the colors do not follow the capacity values. I will share an example.
Here is the case where it unnecessarily changes color
[image: Here is the case where it unnecessarily changes color]
[image: Capacity at these nodes]

Another example - Here the colors should change, but it does not

[image: Here the colors should change, but it does not]
[image: Capacity values at this location]

[The excel files are here for reference](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KOAH9806G1OfBSHhg-0HjA9ThTWCde-Z?usp=sharing)

Also, if you can suggest how to add a color-bar to this, it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import networkx as nx

# dummy data, Graph and positions
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'node1': np.random.choice([*'ABCDEFGHIJKL'], 10, replace=True),
    'node2': np.random.choice([*'ABCDEFGHIJKL'], 10, replace=True),
    'Capacity': np.random.rand(10)
})
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='node1', target='node2', edge_attr='Capacity')
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

# extract the edge weight
edge_colors = [a['Capacity'] for u,v,a in G.edges(data=True)]

# draw nodes and edges separately. allows using colormap for edges.
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, edge_color=edge_colors, edge_cmap=plt.cm.viridis, edge_vmin=0, edge_vmax=np.max(edge_colors), width=5)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos);
```

[image]

Comment: Will 'Capacity' be 'weight' here?

Comment: yes, sorry, didn't update all occurrences. see edited version.

Comment: Okk. But, now I am not getting the node labels. I faced the same problem before also, while plotting nodes and edges by separate commands.

Comment: Alright, you can also draw the labels separately: see latest edit

Comment: Thanks, looks great & seems working. Will try it on the main code.